# Is my paper "better" or "worse" than the journal it is published in?

Tags: journals, bibliometrics

Is there a pseudo-quantitative way to determine from the impact factor, Cite score, or similar, whether an article I published in a journal is an "(under/over)performer" with respect to the journal it is published in?

Comment: Well the [impact factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impact_factor) of a journal is essentially the average number times a paper published in that journal was cited in the previous two years. I suppose you could check the number of citations of your paper over the same time period and see if that exceeds the impact factor of the journal. Although I don't think this would be a very meaningful criteria for variety of reasons. Number of citations is also not a very good measure of the quality of a paper.

Comment: @atom44 it’s not a measure of quality but somehow it’s how the “performance” of a paper is measured in academia?

Comment: in some contexts it's used to measure 'performance' or 'significance', but it's a poor measure of such things. For example, a paper with a major error could get a lot of citations with other researchers criticising it. Review papers also tend to get cited a lot, but they don't really contribute any new knowledge to the field. How meaningful would the citation counts be in these cases?

Comment: I agree on the first part. Well-written review papers can IMO be very influential (in my domain Acta Numerica's papers are often must reads). 
Anyway, this diverges a bit from my question, which was more "statistical".

Comment: Perhaps if you knew the distribution function of the citations per paper you could see if you were more than 1 standard deviation away from the median (although be careful with the statistics since 0 citations is a hard stop on one side). But, really, why bother even thinking about it?

Comment: Mere curiosity! I received an email from Elsevier, I published in one of their journals, giving me the stats for the bibliometric indices for 2021 of that journal. I wondered then: did my article stand out? was it average? was it below average? no greed or desire for more citations, I was simply curious.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://www.nature.com/articles/srep01649